# android: make function to launch the main site of an app

Tags: android, launch, homescreen, main-activity

I have a tutorial how to use my app when it is first launched, but I can't get to my original app. I need a function for opening the main site of my app. 
Tried this but it didn't work:

```
private void launchMainScreen() {
            prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: Are you looking to specify the launcher activity for your app? You do this in the Manifest. Please edit your question to include the Manifest.xml file.

Comment: But I start the Tutorial class in my Manifest

Comment: Hi, please paste your Manifest file as well as your Activity (where the code you pasted came from) - we can help you.